# self referencing table with child table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, hierarchical-data

I have a self-referencing table with content like this:

```
Self-referencing parent table
ID  ParentID    Name
---------------------
1               John
2   1           Mike
3   2           Erin
4   1           Janie
5               Eric
6   5           Peter
```

The tree hierarchy should look like this

- John

  - Mike

    - Erin
  - Janie
- Eric

  - Peter

And a child table that stores the leaf of parent table that looks like this:

```
ID  Sales
3   100
3   100
4   200
4   200
6   300
6   300
6   300
```

I'm trying to roll-up the sum from the leaf node up to the hierarchy so it would return as ..

```
ID  Name    Sum
1   John    800
2   Mike    200
3   Erin    200
4   Janie   400
5   Eric    900
6   Peter   900
```

Any ideas how to achieve this in sql 2008? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT** All aggregation moved out of the CTE

```
WITH
  tree AS
(
  SELECT
    id                AS root_id,
    name              AS root_name,
    id                AS leaf_id
  FROM
    yourTreeTable

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    tree.root_id      AS root_id,
    tree.name         AS root_name,
    yourTreeTable.id  AS leaf_id
  FROM
    tree
  INNER JOIN
    yourTreeTable
      ON tree.leaf_id = yourTreeTable.ParentID
)
SELECT
  tree.root_id,
  tree.root_name,
  COALESCE(SUM(yourScoresTable.score), 0) AS total
FROM
  tree
LEFT JOIN
  yourScoresTable
    ON yourScoresTable.ID = tree.leafID
GROUP BY
  tree.root_id,
  tree.root_name
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond, Dem. I'm getting two error messages with that query: `GROUP BY, HAVING, or aggregate functions are not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'flattend'.` and `Outer join is not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'flattend'.
`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Eric - I'm so out of practice I didn't even remember that wold be the case.  I've re-coded such that all the aggregation is done outside of the CTE.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i had to leave early yesterday and i've been in a meeting the whole morning. The query works like charm. But i had trouble understanding the CTE and how the COALESCE function work. I need to add ParentID column to the result so that i can rebuild the tree structure in the app but i keep getting different count. Can you help a bit more? Thanks again.

Comment: I had this figured out by joining the tree table. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

Let's supose this schema:

```
​create table #parent (
ID int,
ParentID int,
Name varchar(50) );

create table #child (
ID int,
Sales int );
```

The query is self explained:

```
WITH 
  tree AS
(
  SELECT
    id as id_parent,
    id as id
  FROM
    #parent
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    tree.id_parent as id_parent,
    #parent.id AS id
  FROM
    tree
  INNER JOIN
    #parent    
      ON tree.id = #parent.ParentID
)
SELECT
  #parent.id,
  #parent.name,
  COALESCE(SUM(#child.Sales), 0) AS total
FROM
  #parent
LEFT JOIN
  tree
    ON #parent.ID = tree.id_parent
LEFT JOIN
  #child on tree.id = #child.id
GROUP BY
  #parent.id,
  #parent.name
```

CTE returns a list of 'leafs' for each employee (#parent), then query sums all sales for this 'leafs'. [You can test it running](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/123241/).

**EDITED**

Query is fixed.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried to run the query but i noticed the sum of the root node is not correct. The sum for John should be 800 instead of 400.

Comment: @Eric, Fixed. But be carefull, John's sum is 600 not 800  ( jhon = 0, Mike= 0 ,Erin= 100+100,Janie=200+200 )

Comment: my bad. thanks for correcting that. I've spent too many hours on this issue and i finally got i what i need. thanks again.

Comment: i already checked Dems' answer earlier since he answered the question first and his approach is pretty close to solution you gave. Let me know if i'm not doing this the right way. Much appreciate you help.